# Custom like button how do you do it?

Tags: facebook, button, web

I have been using Flipboard for sometime. And on the the app their is a really customized Facebook LIKE button. How do I achieve this for my mobile web app?

Answer (score 0):

"Like" is nothing but a connection available on different Facebook objects like "Albums", "Post" and many others. To create a like you need to issue "HTTP POST" on the click of the button or element you want to represent as a like button. For example to create a like on Album object using PHP SDK :-

```
$likeCreate = $facebook->api("/ALBUM_ID/likes","POST");
```

This creates the like for the user using the application through which this call was initiated and also requires publish_stream permission.